# Canvas jagged line issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've built a very simple line graph using canvas (pulling in data from google analytics). I'm having a few small issues. First off, the plot line is jagged:

http://jsfiddle.net/uJQ7K/

I'm just using lineTo for this:

```
ctx.lineTo((i*cellWidth) + cellWidth + padding,(tableHeight + padding) - data[i].v);
```

I've read that using splines can fix this but surely there's a way to draw a straight line out of the box?

Other problems I'm having are changing one attribute like strokeStyle changes all the strokes on a page. How do I just change the stroke of the plot line and not affect the appearance of the grid?

Comment: the context will "remember" all line drawings up to the next context.beginPath.  The last defined context style settings will be used to redraw all remembered lines.  So, if you want to change styles, put context.beginPath before those newly styled drawings. This will help a bit with your jaggies.  You might thicken your plotline to ctx.lineWidth=3 to help more with the jaggies.

Comment: Thanks. Yes just realised I'd been missing off the beginPath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Have you tried changing your line cap?</s>

<s>cxt.lineCap = 'round';</s>

EDIT -

By adding ctx.beginPath(); before your ctx.lineCap you will get a better result -

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uJQ7K/1/

Comment: Great. Adding that and bumping the lineWidth a bit gives me less jaggies

Comment: amazing!!! that sounds so unbelievable, could you please explain a little bit this *magic* quality improvement?